# How to manage kestrel service that is stopped

Tags: asp.net-core, centos, kestrel

I publish my `AspNetCore` project in `CentOs7 x64` on *kestrel* without any reverse proxy server like `enginx` webServer.

My service stopped sometimes, how can I reset crashed service named kestrel?

I create kestrel service in `/etc/systemd/system` with this bash script:

```
[Unit]
Description=TestProject running on CentOS 7

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/aspnetcore/TestProject
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/aspnetcore/TestProject/WebUi.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if dotnet service crashes
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=root
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Monitoring systems for manage service lifetime.

Zabbix, PRTG and ManageEngine is best monitoring system. usually i use ManageEngine monitoring, that has Events as a sensor of service status. and for each event you can set Action(s), like execute bash script (for reset kestrel service).